# IndexOutOfRange

Tags: powershell, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm getting this error:

```
Array assignment failed because index '3' was out of range.
At Z:\CSP\deploys\aplicacional\teste.ps1:71 char:12
+                 $UNAME[ <<<< $i]= $line
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (3:Int32) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : IndexOutOfRange
```

I really can't find why the index end there.

```
$CSNAME = @(KPScript -c:GetEntryString $PASSHOME\$PASSFILE -pw:$PASS -Field:csname $SEARCH)

$UNAME = @()
$i = 0
Write-Host "Length="$CSNAME.Length
while($i -le $CSNAME.Length)
{
  Write-Host "Start "$i
  #$CSNAME[$i].GetType()
  if ($CSNAME[0].StartsWith("OK:")) {
    Write-Host "ACES $ACES does not exist" -Foreground "red"
  }
  if ($CSNAME[$i].StartsWith("OK:")) {
    break
  }

  Write-Host "CSNAME="$CSNAME[$i]

  $UNAME = $UNAME + $i

  $UNAME = KPScript -c:GetEntryString $PASSHOME\$PASSFILE -pw:$PASS -Field:UserName -ref-csname:$CSNAME[$i]
  foreach ($line in $UNAME) {
    if (! ($line.StartsWith("OK:"))) {
      Write-Host $i
      $UNAME = $UNAME + $i
      Write-Host "uname var"$i
      $UNAME[$i] = $line
    } else {
      Write-Host "break"
      break
    }
  }
  #$UNAME[$i].GetType()
  #if ($UNAME[$i].StartWith("OK:*")){
  #  break
  #}

  Write-Host "UNAME="$UNAME[$i]
  #$UNAME[$i]
  Write-Host "End "$i
  $i += 1
  Write-Host "switch"
}
```

Since the second while is based in the first array length and it has values, why is the it getting out of range?

Comment: Can you please help me understand what KPScript means? is that a kind of external command? what kind of output you get when you fire that command at PowerShell command prompt?

Comment: Your code is a little confusing but the issue has to be that you are using the main index `$i` which is derived from `$CSNAME.length` to index a completely different array `$UNAME` so they clearly don't have the same length. I suggest you explain what is happening here and include some sample text and expected output. I'm sure we can figure this out for you.

Comment: @SavindraSingh kpscript is the cmd utility for accessing keepass databases.

Comment: Ok, so, the object is: for each position of the $CSNAME array, witch has a length of 5, I need to run another kpscript (that Matt very well said it's a keepass command line) to get the UNAME for it. The output is always _something_ /n _OK: something else_. I just need the _something_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell arrays are zero-based, so an array of length 3 has index values from 0 through 2. Your code, however, would iterate from 0 to 3, because the loop condition checks if the variable is less or equal the length (`-le`):

```
while($i -le $CSNAME.Length)
{
  ...
}
```

You need to check if the variable is less than the length (or less or equal the length minus one):

```
while($i -lt $CSNAME.Length)
{
  ...
}
```

Also, you'd normally use a `for` loop for iterating over an array, so you can handle the index variable in one place:

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt $CSNAME.Length; $i++) {
  ...
}
```

---

**Edit:** You initialize `$UNAME` as an array, but inside the loop you assign `$UNAME = KPScript ...`, which replaces the array with whatever the script returns (another array, a string, `$null`, ...). Don't use the same variable for different things in a loop. Assign the script output to a different variable. Also, your way of appending to the array is rather convoluted. Instead of `$UNAME = $UNAME + $i; $UNAME[$i] = $line` simply do `$UNAME += $line`.

```
$res = KPScript -c:GetEntryString $PASSHOME\$PASSFILE -pw:$PASS -Field:UserName -ref-csname:$CSNAME[$i]
foreach ($line in $res) {
  if (! ($line.StartsWith("OK:"))) {
    $UNAME += $line
  } else {
    break
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the 'for loop' suggestion. It really simplified the code. About the problem, the length of the array is 5, so, it shouldn't be  be a problem.

Comment: I removed the $UNAME initialized as an array and changed the code accordingly. Now, the Write-Host $UNAME returns everything in one line: UNAME= spms OK: Operation completed successfully. what is expected is the spms as one line (the one I want) and when it gets to the 'ok:' line, it breaks

Comment: Where did I tell you to remove the array initialization?

Comment: That was my understanding, and in the code you sent, the $res, is not an array

Comment: `$res` is whatever `KPScript` returns. That doesn't have anything to do with `$UNAME` being an array. Leave its initialization as it was.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. Two questions if I may: How do I access each position of the UNAME array? And, would it be better to have a multi-dimensional array since for each CSNAME I will several other values, like U_NAME, PASSWD, IP, etc?

Comment: You access array elements via the index operator (`$UNAME[$i]`). For storing structured information an array of hashtables or a hashtable of hashtables would be a better approach IMO.

Comment: Doing write-host "UNAME="$UNAME[$i] I get UNAME= 0; UNAME= spms; UNAME= 1; UNAME= spms. They should all be, for this case, 'spms'

Comment: That's because you still have `$UNAME = $UNAME + $i` in your code. Remove it. It doesn't have any purpose anyway.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, really appreciate it. I'll do some tests with the hashtables later on.